# C# ternary operator with null check not behaving properly

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, conditional-operator

C# ternary operator with null check not behaving properly

```
"City updated from old value '" + isOtherAccountExist == null ? "EMPTY" :isOtherAccountExist.City + "' to ' something else"
```

In the above statement, expectation is if `isOtherAccountExist=null` then it should simply return instead of checking for `isOtherAccountExist.City` value. but its checking and throwing `NullReference` Exception.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Comment: Check your operator precedence table. `+` has higher precedence than `?`. (Edit: Fixed typo.)

Comment: Put the ternary expression in parentheses: `(isOtherAccountExist == null ? "EMPTY" : isOtherAccountExist.City)`. Or the shorter version: `(isOtherAccountExist?.City ?? "EMPTY")`. Note that the latter will also use "EMPTY" if the `City` property is null (which is probably what you want to happen).

Comment: You need to put the tenary expression in parentheses as has been said, what this is doing is essentially doing now is `if ("City updated from old value" + isOtherAccountExists) { "EMPTY" } else { isOtherAccountExist.City + ' to ' something else" }`.

The `+` operator is taking precedence here.

Answer (score 0):

```
string isOtherAccountExist = "";

string value = isOtherAccountExist == null ? "EMPTY" : isOtherAccountExist;

Console.WriteLine(
    $"City updated from old value {value} to something else");
```

Comment: you removed `.City` from the scene, which was the center of the problem